# Set Elasticsearch node name on Logstash client

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

When my logstash indexers connect to Elasticsearch they show up as "logstash-localhost-xxxxx-xxxxx" where the x's are digits. Does anyone know how to set the node name or to make them show up with their hostname instead? I am on CentOS 6 and am installing v1.5 from the official repositories.

Comment: I think you need to specify the `node_name` for the `elasticsearch` output in LS: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-node_name

Comment: @AndreiStefan That did it... post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `node_name` for the `elasticsearch` output in LS: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-node_name

> node_name
>
> Value type is string
>   There is no default value for this setting.
>   The node name Elasticsearch will use when joining a cluster.
>
> By default, this is generated internally by the ES client.